How come the jest mock is not capturing the requests that I mock(slack web-api)
Been fighting it for a while, but tried all variations of slack web-api mocks that I found and none of them is working for me, so I thought I'll share it here and maybe someone will have an idea what's I'm missing here.
Here is the structure of my jest test file:
import ....(all the imports)

describe('my slack tests', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    // Mock slack web api
    jest.mock('@slack/web-api', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('@slack/web-api'),
    
      WebClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        auth: {
          test: () => Promise.resolve({ ok: true }),
        },
        conversations: {
          list: () => Promise.resolve({ ok: true,
                                        response_metadata: {},
                                        channels: [
                                          {name: 'test_channel', id: 'AAABBB123456'}, 
                                          {name: 'ABCD1234', id: 'AAABBB123457'},
                                        ] }),
        },
      })),
    }));
  });
  test('My Test', async () => {
    ...Calling a function that calls the WebClient.conversations.list(...)...
    ... Verified the function works outside the test with proper token....
  });
});

I'm certain I'm missing something here, but not sure what.
The result I'm getting from that is the following error 'Error: An API error occurred: invalid_auth' - to me this is saying that the api call is probably going to the real slack API and the mock is not capturing the request.
Any assistance or ideas will be greatly appreciated.
I tried all possible variations of that same mock that I found online and all of them behaved the same - as if there was no mock.

After few attempts at the issue it seems that just pulling the jest.mock out of the describe block resolves the issue.
For whoever is seeing similar issues, keep the jest mock at the top of the file and outside of any functions/code blocks.
